# iPhone 5 4 Inch Screen Update

Tags: iphone, xcode, user-interface, ios6, iphone-5

I'm updating my app for the iPhone 5. Now I've read the topics about setting the Autosize Property and I've done that.

My question is regarding some of my elements. The interface of the app is really simple. It uses a pre-defined apple background (no custom images), and has 4 labels and a Information Button.

Two of the labels are fine but the other two and the button are aligned with the bottom of the screen, but with Auto-Sizing it creates and 1/2 inch of background between them and edge of screen.

If there any way to make them stay at the bottom of the screen like that but without having to create a whole new view for iPhone 5, with them positioned right and them programmtically select it when needed, as that is a slightly too complex way for the sake of two labels and a button.

EDITED

Here is some screenshots.

Should look like this (iPhone 4S 3.5 Inch Screen)

[linky](http://imageshack.us/a/img641/6280/iossimulatorscreenshot2.png)

Does look like this (iPhone 5 4 Inch Screen)

[linky](http://imageshack.us/a/img546/6280/iossimulatorscreenshot2.png)

Comment: Have you set the autosizingMask of the Label and the Infobutton correctly?

Answer (score 0):

To get the expected behaviour while using Autolayout, in Interface Builder, you need to select the two labels in the bottom and then go to

> Editor -> Pin -> Bottom Space to Superview

This will make sure that the bottom spacing is as expected.